# Using sed to change / in date format to

Tags: bash, shell, date, sed, format

I need to change the date format from `dd/mm/yyyy` to `dd.mm.yyyy` using `sed`.
I have tried to do it this way:

```
sed 's,[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

but that obviously does not work. How do i keep the same dates while only switching the slash for the period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your separators (commas, in your case, but usually slashes) in the right places.

You also need backreferences. These are items on the left side enclosed with (escaped) parantheses, which are available on the right side using \1, \2, etc.

```
sed 's,\([0-9][0-9]\)/\([0-9][0-9]\)/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\),\1.\2.\3,'
```

You can also shorten the syntax by indicating the number of characters to match inside (escaped) braces:

```
sed 's,\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\([0-9]\{4\}\),\1.\2.\3,'
```

For your particular situation, it would be simpler to use `tr '/' '.'` instead of sed for the same effect.

Comment: The `{` and `}` need escaping for the second call to work. Or you could use the extended regex syntax and write `sed -r 's,([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4}),\1.\2.\3,'` Other than that, spot on.

Comment: Ah, right. Fixed. Thanks. Also, `sed -E` (rather than `sed -r`) on BSD systems (at least OS X, anyway).

Comment: @user3344218 You may narrow down the regex some,  there are no date or month like 48, 68 etc. `sed 's,\([0-2][0-9]\)/\([0-1][0-9]\)/\([1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]\),\1.\2.\3,'`